# CSS JS HTML Get background to top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know how do good describe this effect.

How to get this in pure css/html ?

[click to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEcOv.png)

I mean:

1 layer - div with background image

2 layer blue overlay with mix-blen-mode multipy

3 layer with countdown skip layer 2 and shows background from layer 1

Any ideas?

Regards.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to make it in Photoshop as one image and then just put the text over it via html?

Comment: @Lucas, could you try some code? tips: you can use `position: absolute` CSS property to adjust elements in a `div{position:relative}` and you can use `opacity` CSS property.

Comment: Please post some code, even if it's only the background image, a div with said mix-blend-mode and the text of the countdown plus some borders

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we put it as a single image and text over it?
Anyways, it's a raster image and not svg, so you can have different background-images for different resolutions and manage it vis css media queries.

Guess, you cannot use multiple layering as you mentioned.

Comment: `you cannot use multiple layering as you mentioned.`… Are you sure? ;) (no, you're wrong, @VishalKaul)

Comment: I said that due to the box that shows time is partially on both the blue and the main image layer.It may have problems in handling opacity issues as it shows the bottommost layer through it. The solution suggested below is displayed fine with respect to the position but it may have issues in handling opacity so that it shows the bottommost layer. I am still curious to see if it works via multi-layered solutions.

Comment: Difficult but not impossible ;).

Comment: sure  .  Looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do…

Not 100% OK, but near. The better solution: [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) (LOL).

```css
div#main_container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F53;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  div#grey_mask_left {
    opacity:.55;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:20%;
    height:40%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#grey_mask_nearleft {
    opacity:.55;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:20%;
    width:4%;
    height:40%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#grey_mask_nearleft:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -27%;
    left: 8%;
    width: 780%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
    background-color: #707070;
    opacity: .9;
    z-index:1;
  }
  div#grey_mask_right {
    opacity:.55;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:20%;
    height:40%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#grey_mask_nearright {
    opacity:.55;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:20%;
    width:4%;
    height:40%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#grey_mask_nearright:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -27%;
    right: -10%;
    width: 722%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 2em 2em 0;
    background-color: #707070;
    opacity: .9;
    z-index:1;
  }
  div#grey_mask_top {
    opacity:0.10;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#grey_mask_bottom {
    opacity:.55;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:24%;
    width:52%;
    height:31%;
    background-color:black;
  }
  div#main_container div#clockwork {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 2em;
    height: 20%;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  div#main_container div#register {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 1em;
    height: 7%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 40%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  <div id="grey_mask_top"></div>
  <div id="grey_mask_left"></div>
  <div id="grey_mask_nearleft"></div>
  <div id="grey_mask_nearright"></div>
  <div id="grey_mask_right"></div>
  <div id="grey_mask_bottom"></div>
  <div id="clockwork"></div>
  <div id="register">Register</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I did in other way:

double backgorund as layer 1 and 3 and for 3 layer:

-webkit-clip-path: inset(5% 20% 200px 20% round 100px 100px);